# Yarn Start is failing to generate CRKA project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, npm, yarnpkg

I'm just trying to start using CRKA to start a project and am immediately getting errors. I use windows and have installed npm, node and yarn through nvm-windows. I used the following command:

```
yarn create react-kotlin-app confexplorer
```

and got the following

> Success! Created confexplorer at
>   D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer Inside that
>   directory, you can run several commands:
>
> yarn start
>       Starts the development server.
>
> yarn build
>       Bundles the app into static files for production.
>
> yarn test
>       Starts the test runner.
>
> yarn eject
>       Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
>       and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!
>
> We suggest that you begin by typing:
>
> cd confexplorer   yarn start
>
> Happy hacking! Done in 161.19s.

Then I did the following without any other changes

```
D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact>cd confexplorer

D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer>yarn start
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts-kotlin start
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.171/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
Starting the development server...

D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer\node_modules\react-scripts-kotlin\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer\node_modules\.cache\kotlin-webpack'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:834:3)
    at KotlinWebpackPlugin.generateErrorBundle (D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer\node_modules\@jetbrains\kotlin-webpack-plugin\plugin.js:249:10)
    at KotlinWebpackPlugin.compileIfFirstRun (D:\GitHub\kotlin-projects\kotlinreact\confexplorer\node_modules\@jetbrains\kotlin-webpack-plugin\plugin.js:199:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'D:\\GitHub\\kotlin-projects\\kotlinreact\\confexplorer\\node_modules\\.cache\\kotlin-webpack'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When any folder along the given path is missing, mkdir will throw an ENOENT. Please show some code

Comment: What other code would be helpful?

Comment: The reason that I think is, if any of the folders exist along the path given to fs.mkdir(object.mkdir) or fs.mkdirSync(in your case object.mkdirSync) these methods will throw/callback with an ENOENT error.

Comment: So you think they're already there Sachin? I've redone everything from scratch several times in different folders and reinstalled npm and yarn

Comment: upgrade NodeJS and Navigate to a directory and type

npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: that works but I'm trying to do a react Kotlin app which still isn't working